# is extending views in rails jbuilder possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I want to index children in "`parent#show`" and the first thing everybody thinks about is using partials. well yeah, that would be ok, but then i have to create both `show.json.jbuilder` for `child#show` and `_show.json.jbuilder` for `parent#show` which this is not clean.

is there any way to handle this? can i extend a view or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. I created show.json.jbuilder first, and then tried to use it as a partial in index.json.jbuilder.

My workaround/solution:

Moved file show.json.jbuilder to _show.json.jbuilder, and renamed all instances of "@mymodel" with local variable "mymodel"

In show.json.jbuilder, I called the partial and passed my instance variable as a local:

`json.partial! 'mymodel/show', mymodel: @mymodel`

In index.json.jbuilder, I used the same partial:

`json.array! @mymodel, partial: 'mymodel/show', as: :mymodel`